# Why is my IPN Listener not receiving data sent from my paypal sandbox?

Tags: php, testing, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have looked through all answers on google and this site - none have helped.

My code consists of the standard IPN Listener code:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

I have made sure the url in use is the sandbox one, not production. I send an IPN via the IPN simulator on PayPal and it says `Successfully sent, and handshake verified.` Which implies that my listener responded with a success. However, when I actually visit /ipn.php it simply says UNVERIFIED, and does not pick up any of the POST data sent from paypal. I test this at the moment by firstly sending the IPN, then refreshing my /ipn.php to see if it picked up the POST data, which it doesn't. What am I missing? Please do ask for any other details.

Answer (score 0):

The POST data from PayPal sits in the `$raw_post_data` variable. If you don't do anything with it (such as store in a database, flat file, etc), it's simply list.
If you would want to see the IPN validation result when you do a GET /ipn.php HTTP request (which is what your browser does when you pull up ipn.php in your browser), you would need to add logic which returns the latest IPN validation status.

Which probably isn't what you'd want.
Instead, step through the sample script provided by PayPal and look at `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {`: what this allows you to do, is add logic to, for example, write the results to a file. Or store it in a database and flip an order state to 'paid'.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing some issue with PayPal, could you please help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46483056/5743676