# Payment error: PayPal error: Invalid request. See details. (VALIDATION_ERROR) Paypal

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm working with PayPal recurring payments in my project. And I want to give one free trial for some amount of time period, and initial order total should be zero, once free trial has completed the actual amount of order will be deducted from account.

For instance, user purchase one product($100 USD) and apply discount code for free trial then first order should be placed with $0 USD, once trial over, $100 USD cycle will running up.

For that I'm passing "0" to `setup_fee` in `MerchantPreferences`:

```
merchant_preferences = new MerchantPreferences
{
    return_url = url,
    cancel_url = url,
    auto_bill_amount = "YES",
    setup_fee = new PayPal.Api.Currency
    {
        currency = currency != null ? currency.CurrencyCode : null,
        value = "0.00"
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> Payment error: PayPal error: Invalid request. See details. (VALIDATION_ERROR)
>   Payment error: note Note is missing from the request or Note length is too long
>   
>   Payment error: amount.currency Required field is missing.

If I pass some values instead of `0.00` it's working properly, but I want to send zero as initial amount.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The errors describe a missing 'Note' parameter and an invalid 'currency'. Have you checked that you are not sending a `null` value for `currency`, or skipping sending the `Note` parameter, when the value is `0`? It seems possible from your code, that if either `currency` is `null` or `currency.CurrencyCode` is `null`, you are sending a `null` value where PayPal does not allow this.

On a side note, I know that many financially driven sites work with a deposit value of ~1 cent, rather than 0, to verify that money is properly transferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!, *Have you checked that you are not sending a null value for currency* As I stated in que. if I'm passing value instead of `0.00` it works, not sure about note parameters, I'm not able to find any note param. in PayPal doc.

Comment: Keep in mind it is theoretically also possible that the currency type is different when `value <= 0`, depends on the rest of the code

Comment: If I configure with value 0.00 it placing order at PayPal, though getting error at my website.